# Mysterious SOSL results for Product2: adding term increases number of results

Tags: sosl, product

I am running SOSL queries on the Product2 table and I am getting results that I don't understand. Our Product2 table contains about 17,000 items, most of them tyres. A typical product name is "215/75R17.5 BRIDGESTONE M788 126/124M TL M+S 3PMSF". The Product2 table has a number of other attributes, of which Brand is one (which would contain "Bridgestone" for this item). SOSL will search all fields of the Product2 table even though I only specify two (that's a feature).

I will run a number of SOSL queries and show how many results are returned:

```
FIND {215 75 17} IN ALL Fields RETURNING Product2(Name, ProductCode ORDER BY Name)
```

-> 157, of which 12 have brand Bridgestone

```
FIND {215 75 17.5} IN ALL Fields RETURNING Product2(Name, ProductCode ORDER BY Name)
```

-> 84, of which just 6 have brand Bridgestone

```
FIND {215 75 17.5 bridge} IN ALL Fields RETURNING Product2(Name, ProductCode ORDER BY Name)
```

-> 12, all of them have brand Bridgestone

The first difference, going from 157 to 84, is already strange: all results contain the string 17.5, so going from 17 to 17.5 should not have made a difference. But maybe it could be explained by the fact that 17 and 17.5 are within a larger string, they are not the start of a string, so that the used search index is not optimal.

But the second difference is what baffles me: adding a search term, which, according to the [Salesforce help page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl_find.htm), should be considered an extra AND condition, returns more Bridgestone results.

Why is that? Elementary database query logic dictates that adding an AND condition can never increase the number of results.

Comment: The 17 and 17.5 changes are likely explained when you consider that search indexing splits the data at word and punctuation points (as per the documentation you referenced "The search engine splits record information separated by spaces or punctuation into separate tokens". The decimal dot is a punctuation character. The second point - note that AND is not always applied by default (it depends on the context, again as per the documentation you cited). I would suggest explicit definition of the operators and see if that changes things for you.

Comment: @PhilW Adding AND between all search terms has no effect: I get the exact same results.

Comment: Cool. That at least excludes one possible cause. What happens if you avoid including punctuation in your search terms? (So avoid 17.5, for example.) Or ensure that you enclose values with punctuation in them in quotes to ensure it is taken as a phrase... (So use "17.5" for example).

Comment: Adding quotes does not make any difference. Using 17 instead of 17.5 however makes all the difference, that gives consistent results.